# ordering boxplots based on two factor variables (in x-axis) with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a large data frame with 3 variables: symbols, vaf, Gene.function. (link to df: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6ykbzuy8x19psp/df_SO.txt?dl=0).

```
 dim(df)
[1] 2021    3
```

I am trying to create a figure with several boxplots and arrange them according to the variable “Gene.function” and the x-axis being “symbols”.
I do not care about the order it-self on the x-axis but I do want all the genes (symbols) having the same category to be one after the other just as in this example here:

[image]

The closest I've been to achieving my goal it’s been by using the forcast library but, for some reason, not all genes with the same “Gene.function” are ordered together. This is the code I’ve used:

```
B <- df %>%
  mutate(symbol = fct_reorder(symbol, Gene.function)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(symbol), y = vaf, fill = factor(Gene.function), color = factor(Gene.function))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x * 100, '%')) +
  xlab('') + 
  ylab('') + 
  ggtitle ('VAF distribution')+
  guides(fill = 'none')+
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 10, hj = 0.5, vj = 0.5, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = 'italic'))
```

I believe the problem is that none of the variables I am using are numeric, instead, both are factors (symbol and Gene.functions). Indeed, I get the following warnings when running the code above:

```
There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `symbol`.
i argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
i Input `symbol` is `fct_reorder(symbol, Gene.function)`.
2: Problem with `mutate()` input `symbol`.
i argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
i Input `symbol` is `fct_reorder(symbol, Gene.function)`.
3: Problem with `mutate()` input `symbol`.
i argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
i Input `symbol` is `fct_reorder(symbol, Gene.function)`.
4: Problem with `mutate()` input `symbol`.
i argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
i Input `symbol` is `fct_reorder(symbol, Gene.function)`.
(...)
```

Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first order the `df` according to the `Gene.function` and `symbol`, then you can take the information about the order of the `symbol`s to create the correct factor level order:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

level_info <- df %>%
  arrange(Gene.function, symbol) %>% 
  pull(symbol) %>% 
  unique()

df %>%
  mutate(Gene.function = as.factor(Gene.function),
         symbol = factor(symbol, levels = level_info)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = symbol, y = vaf, fill = Gene.function, color = Gene.function)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x * 100, '%')) +
  xlab('') + 
  ylab('') + 
  ggtitle ('VAF distribution')+
  guides(fill = 'none')+
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 10, hj = 0.5, vj = 0.5, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = 'italic'))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I had tried to do it with dplyr but wasn't using it properly! Thanks